# Excel: Compare 2 cell values; If 5 or more consecutive characters matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare

I'm trying to compare a cell with a list of other values.

Cell A2 = Stockholm

with list =
Stockholm
Stockholm S
Stockholm C

The cell is based on user input, and therefore it might say Stockh or Stockholm City sometimes based on personal use. Therefore I want a function that can compare and give me TRUE if at least 5 consecutive characters match between the cell A2 and the list.

E.g. Stockh matches with all of them in this example.

Is there a good function for this? Or do I need to do a hack/bodge for this to work?

Comment: With VBA you can create an UDF to do exactly what you want. With normal excel formulas you can just compare the whole string or a specific 5 char string inside A2, but not all possible 5 chars strings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example I drew up, based on what you mentioned:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>4,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(A1,5),C1:C3)))>0)
```

Or, as per your comment, we can revert the logic and look up all substrings from our list in cell `A1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(LEFT(C1:C3,5),A1)))>0
```

Where `WAAR` stands for `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you! If works good!
Can I adjust it to not just look from the left? Sometimes the user inputs "(Stockholm)" or "->Stockholm". 

Can it just look up anywhere in the cell, not just from left?

Comment: Well, in that case we can revert the theory and look up the first 5 characters of the list in cell `A1`. I've edited the answer to reflect that @JerryOnmalm.

Comment: Looks good, also added a UPPERCASE() for both (C1:C3) and A1 for it to discard case sensitivity, and now it looks really good. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: @JerryOnmalm. To discard case sensitivity you should use `SEARCH()` instead of `FIND()`. Also, if this has answered your question you should accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, new to the site so I didn't know. Again, thank you!

Comment: @JerryOnmalm, if you are new, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also have a look at [ask] a question for future reference. Notice your question is currently closed due to unclarity? You can prevent this in the future by writing better questions. GL with the formula =)